# How to properly convert Pytube bufferIO to numpy array representing sine wave?

Tags: python, numpy, audio, buffer, pytube

**Problem**: I'm trying to download audio from Youtube via Pytube, save it to buffer (**I don't want to save the audio to drive**) and then convert it to numpy array in order to plot a raw audio wave. After conversion I'm trying to convert it back to sound and instead of 12 minutes of audio from a video, I'm getting 12 seconds of static noise. When saving buffer to .mp4 everything seems to be working just fine. I'm quite lost and would appreciate any help.

**Program**:

```py
from IPython.display import Audio
from pytube import YouTube
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrqqrQmeQS4')

# getting audio stream
audioStreams = list(map(lambda streamObj: streamObj.itag, yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True)))
activeStream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(audioStreams[0])

# saving to buffer
bufferObj = BytesIO()
activeStream.stream_to_buffer(bufferObj)

# saving buffer to ndarray
bufferObj.seek(0)
points_array = np.frombuffer(bufferObj.read())

# preprocessing raw numpy data
points_array = np.round(points_array,10)
points_array[np.isinf(points_array) | np.isnan(points_array)] = 0

return Audio(points_array, rate=44.1 * 1000)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to interpret the data as an array of floats?

Answer (score 2):

Let's untackle a few issues:

**1.** `points_array = np.frombuffer(bufferObj.read())`

With this line, you're interpreting the gained data (byte) as float64 which is the default `dtype` of `np.frombuffer` *(as can be seen in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html))*. Audio data as you want to process it, is usually stored in a format like [`16-bit PCM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth).
To fix the underlying issue, we need to use a module that knows how to interpret the audio data appropriately. I'm using `pydub` to convert the audio to WAV format which then can be read by `scipy`.

**2.** `points_array = np.round(points_array,10)`

Similar to before, this would imply that the audio data is in floating point format, but it's not. As previously stated, we are using an integer format (like signed 16-bit PCM). On an off-topic note: If you're trying to normalize the audio data *("preprocessing")*, you should divide it by the maximum possible value (so for 16-bit it would be `2^15 - 1 = 32767`.

**3.** `return Audio(points_array, rate=44.1 * 1000)`

Lastly, down the road this hard-coded rate will do you no good. You should rather extract the sample rate (when reading the audio with `scipy`).

Now the whole script works. Here is the full code (including the fixed lines as specified above):

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pydub import AudioSegment
from io import BytesIO
from scipy.io.wavfile import read as wav_read
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import Audio

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrqqrQmeQS4')

# Getting audio stream
audioStreams = list(map(lambda streamObj: streamObj.itag, yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True)))
activeStream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(audioStreams[0])

# Saving to buffer
bufferObj = BytesIO()
activeStream.stream_to_buffer(bufferObj)

# Using pydub to read audio data from the buffer
audio = AudioSegment.from_file(bufferObj, format="mp4")

# Convert audio to wav format and then save it to a new buffer
bufferObj = BytesIO()
audio.export(bufferObj, format="wav")
bufferObj.seek(0)

# Now we can properly load this into numpy
sample_rate, audio_array = wav_read(bufferObj)

# Preprocessing raw numpy data
audio_array = np.round(audio_array,10)
audio_array[np.isinf(audio_array) | np.isnan(audio_array)] = 0

# Display the audio
Audio(audio_array, rate=sample_rate)
```

Note: Don't forget to install `pydub` and `scipy` to make it work.

By the way, in the process of writing the answer I faced some issues due to YouTube's recent changes. I followed the fix in [issue #1707](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1707) by searching for the location of the `pytube` directory.

```
>>> import pytube
>>> print(pytube.__file__)
```

And then changing the line `r'var {nfunc}\s*=\s*(\[.+?\]);'.format(` to `r'var {nfunc}\s*=\s*(\[.+?\])'.format(` (i.e. removing the `;` from the RegEx statement).

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, but there is another problem related to ffmpeg now at line where you've suggested to read audio data via pydub in "mp4" format:
```py
CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 1
[cache @ 000001812f581d00] Inner protocol failed to seekback end : -40
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001812f580cc0] moov atom not found
[cache @ 000001812f581d00] Statistics, cache hits:0 cache misses:0
cache:pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: @JoshJohnson Have you checked your `ffmpeg` installation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [soundfile](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/)

> SoundFile can read and write sound files. File reading/writing is supported through libsndfile, which is a free, cross-platform, open-source (LGPL) library for reading and writing many different sampled sound file formats that runs on many platforms including Windows, OS X, and Unix. It is accessed through CFFI, which is a foreign function interface for Python calling C code. CFFI is supported for CPython 2.6+, 3.x and PyPy 2.0+. SoundFile represents audio data as NumPy arrays.

```
from IPython.display import Audio
from pytube import YouTube
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
import soundfile as sf

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrqqrQmeQS4')

# Getting audio stream
audioStreams = list(map(lambda streamObj: streamObj.itag, yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True)))
activeStream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(audioStreams[0])

# Saving to buffer
bufferObj = BytesIO()
activeStream.stream_to_buffer(bufferObj)

# Seek to the beginning of the buffer
bufferObj.seek(0)

# Convert buffer to audio data using soundfile
audio_data, sample_rate = sf.read(bufferObj)

# Preprocessing raw audio data
audio_data = np.round(audio_data, 10)
audio_data[np.isinf(audio_data) | np.isnan(audio_data)] = 0

# Display audio using IPython's Audio
return Audio(audio_data, rate=sample_rate)
```